# Java Cast from Object[] to double[] array and Double[] to double[] array

Tags: types

Is there a way to cast an `Object[]` array into `double[]` array without using any loops. And cast `Double[]` array to `double[]` array

Comment: This answers the second part of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109988/how-do-i-convert-double-to-double

Comment: The above link says, I have to use loop, which I want to avoid. Java definitely failed here in comparison to .net (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741350/how-does-c-sharp-generics-affect-collections-with-primitives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2013 we haven't Java [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), just in march of 2014. With it you can get your answer:

**From Object[] to double[]**

```
Object[] objectArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

double[] convertedArray = Arrays.stream(objectArray) // converts to a stream
    .mapToDouble(num -> Double.parseDouble(num.toString())) // change each value to Double
    .toArray(); // converts back to array
```

**From Double[] to double[]**

```
Double[] doubleArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

double[] conv = Arrays.stream(doubArray)
    .mapToDouble(num -> Double.parseDouble(num.toString()))
    .toArray();
```

You notice that it's the same operation, since the resulting type for both conversions are **double[]**. What is changed is the source data.

*PS: what a late answer :|*

Comment: Better late than never :)