# Cannot debug on Android 7.0 device

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2.  I didn't have any problems with debugging multi-device apps on a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge 
before the OS was updated from Android Marshmallow 6.0.1 to Nougat 7.0.

When I start debugging, I see this error :

[image]

The result is that I cannot debug. But the app is somehow installed on the device.

I tried to fix the error by:

```
- updating the Android SDK to version 25.3.1 + NDK + JDK update.  
- setting `-cleaninstall` in the debugger parameters.  
- resetting the mobile phone to factory settings.
```

Unfortunatelly, none of the above worked for me.

The particular app is not the cause of the problems, because I tried also with Delphi sample code and the result is the same.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I have same problem and can not find solotion

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- update the SDK Tools (new version available is 25.2.5)
- update the SDK Platform-tools (new version available is 25.0.3)
- install SDK Platform and the ARM EABI v7a System Image for Android 7.0 (API 24).

Comment: use -autolaunch in run->parameters: see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741366)